# How to provide a Google Build trigger access to a Google SQL DB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-build

Is there a way to grant access to a Google Build trigger for a Google SQL DB? I want to migrate my database based on updates to my migration files. So when my master branch is updated, the ci build trigger will update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the service account linked to your Google Build, edit it and add the roles that you need in order to grant the access to Google Cloud SQL (for editing and updating might recommend: `Cloud SQL Editor`), [Grant additional access](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#granting_additional_access).